# how to slide all the columns name in a dataframe to the left?

Tags: python, dataframe, csv, txt

I have a dataframe (25000, 20000). The original format is like this
[image]

I would like to make it become like this

[image]

by using python. Can anyone give a help?

Answer (score 0):

Try this; Assuming you wish to have the last column be part of your final data without any column name...

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"":[1,2,3],
                   "a":[4,5,6],
                   "b":[7,8,9]})

a = ""
df.columns = list(df.columns[1:]) + [a]

# Output of df;
   a  b   
0  1  4  7
1  2  5  8
2  3  6  9
```

Comment: Thank you. Actually I would like to save it in txt file, with the last column name is NULL. In your example, the "column_name" must be disappear.

Comment: So, "column_name" must be disappear... I'm assuming you don't wish to have this column in final dataset... & have edited the code accordingly... Hope this Helps...

Comment: Thank you. But in the txt file, I still want to keep the last column's value (7 8 9), but it's name is NULL. I'm trying to do open a new file and write every single row to it, but still not work.

Comment: Ok... Edited answer again... Last column will be there & column name will be the value of variable "a"... Feel free to edit the variable "a" to see the change in column name of last variable...